# Is there a Drag & Drop for wxPython?

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

A drag-and-drop interface for text boxes, check boxes, etc. Otherwise it's hard to make apps, because you have to memorize the commands, and it takes forever to type all of the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try Boa Constructor - it is dated - but it is targeted at WX -

http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What do you mean dated?